# SPO multiple subsite renaming - powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, pnp-powershell

Excel played a little trick on me removing 0 and 00 in front of subsites URL for a migration I did.

I migrated subsites from on premise farm to online using a CSV, but without noticing, excel removed the zeros in front of the subsites URL.

So I now have **400 subsites** that **had a 0 or 00 in front** like this
(original on premise subsite url- **/sites/0012345**

and imported to this subsite online to- **/sites/12345/** removing the two zeros in front.

I'm trying to automate this as I have 400+ subsite to rename, using PnP or any suggestion welcome.

So I want to rename all 400+ sites online adding them back the 0 or 00 in front.

Found this script online but don't want to use this 400 times, would there be an easier way?

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
#Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"
$OldSiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/ops"
$NewSiteUrl = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/operations"
#Connect to SharePoint Online from PnP PowerShell
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminSiteURL -Interactive
#Change sharepoint online site url powershell
Rename-PnPTenantSite -Identity $OldSiteURL -NewSiteUrl $NewSiteUrl
```

Comment: create a mapping in csv file (i.e. old url and new url). Read data from this CSV. Loop over each row and get the respective input and perform update.

Comment: shared the sample code .... you can refer it

Comment: Thanks, really a good start, this helped me a lot. See answer below, that ended up working for our tenant.

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Rohit, this indeed was I was looking to do.

Unfortunatly, found out that the Rename-PnpTenantSite function does not work on Multi-Geo tenant, such as ours.
Also, the interactive login didn't work, so ended up using the -UseWebLogin instead.

I also ended up looking at other scripts and here is what worked, a combination of your script + the below :

```
$inputCSV     = "c:/temp/test.csv"  #specify path of your CSV file here
$siteDetails  = Import-CSV $inputCSV

$siteDetails | ForEach-Object{
    $SiteURL = $_.OldSiteUrl  #csv column A
    $NewURL = $_.NewSiteUrl   #csv column B 

    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

    $Web = Get-PnPWeb
    $Web.ServerRelativeUrl = $NewURL
    $Web.Update()

    Invoke-PnPQuery
    Write-host "Subsite has been Renamed!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Note, in the CSV, you need to use the following full url for the OldSiteUrl and relative path for the NewSiteUrl as seen below :

- OldSiteUrl : https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/subsite/12345
- NewSiteUrl : /sites/subsite/0012345

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputCSV     = "./InputToUpdateUrl.csv"  #specify path of your CSV file here
$siteDetails  = Import-CSV $inputCSV
$adminSiteUrl = "https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminSiteURL -Interactive

$siteDetails | ForEach-Object{

    $oldSiteUrl = $_.OldSiteUrl 
    $newSiteUrl = $_.NewSiteUrl
    
    Rename-PnPTenantSite -Identity $OldSiteURL -NewSiteUrl $NewSiteUrl  
}
```

Refer below Image for same CSV:

[image]